# Exportar a Excel reporte de jaspersoft studio

Tags: jasper-reports

He creado un reporte en **jaspersoft** y lo he llamado de un software (de código java realizado en eclipse) al presionar un botón de generar informe, el cual genera o muestra correctamente el informe.

El problema es cuando quiero exportarlo a **Excel** ya que cuando le digo guardar en formato xls, si bien me pide ubicación y nombre para guardarlo.

No lo hace, ya que si vamos a la ubicación que le indicamos no esta el archivo.

Cabe mencionar que si realizo el mismo procedimiento para guardar en PDF, Doc, HTML.

Lo guarda correctamente pero para excel (que sería el que más me interesa) no funciona. También hay que decir que desde el Jaspersof directamente si me deja guardar en Excel. gracias si me pueden ayudar... Andrés!

### Este es mi código java:

```
@Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Coneccion con=null;
            con=new Coneccion();
            JasperPrint jasperPrintWindow;
            try {
                jasperPrintWindow = JasperFillManager.fillReport(
//      "C:\\Users\\Andres\\JaspersoftWorkspace\\MyReports\\reportePrimero.jasper", null,
        "C:\\Users\\Andres\\JaspersoftWorkspace\\MyReports\\enBuscadelExcel.jasper", null,
                        con.get_Miconexion());

                JasperViewer jasperViewer = new JasperViewer(jasperPrintWindow);
                jasperViewer.setVisible(true);
            } catch (JRException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                try {
                      con.close();
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                    // LOG
                  }
            }
           }
```

Comment: Podrias editar tu pregunta y agregar el codigo de java que ya tienes

Comment: la direccion del archivo esta dos veces.. porq probe con un segundo archivo para ver si el problema no era el primero.. pero no.. hace lo mismo

Comment: Solo no pones en el codigo donde le pones la extención al archivo

Comment: @RaulCacacho el codigo para llamar al reporte lo copie tal cual lo encontre en un totorial de jaspersoft.. en realidad no se bien donde debería incluir lo q me dices.. sera q me puede enviar como quedaría .. gracias

Comment: ¿Cuando le das a guardar has visto si te lanza alguna `Exception` en el programa Java, algo así más o menos: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/RichTextString
 at net.sf.jasperreports.view.save.JRSingleSheetXlsSaveContributor.save(JRSingleSheetXlsSaveContributor.java:111)`?

Comment: hola @A.Cedano gracias por contestar. mira, no me había fijado en eso ya que para los demás formatos me funcionaba bien no pensé que tendría algún poroblema en eso. Pero efectivamente me genera la excepción que tu mencionas. Así que si me ayudas a dilisidar que es lo que esta mal, te lo agradecería. yo voy a intentar indagar por ese lado también.. muchas gracias

Comment: Raul, podrias compartirnos la clase ReporteJasper Gracias de antemano
Eduardo Beltran

Answer (score 1):

Yo tengo un código parecido al tuyo en el que muestro el reporte en un viewer.

Efectivamente, al intentar guardar el reporte desde el viewer tenía errores del tipo:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/RichTextString at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.view.save.JRSingleSheetXlsSaveContributor.save(JRSingleSheetXlsSaveContributor.java:111)

Lo he resuelto agregando al proyecto la librería [`POI`de Apache](http://poi.apache.org/download.html#POI-3.17), la cual es requerida para exportar los reportes a Excel.

Después de agregar dicha librería a mi proyecto, la exportación se hace sin ningún problema, pudiendo crear un archivo Excel al pulsar el botón `Guardar`.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo hago con esta clase donde solo la mando a llamar cuando necesito un metodo.

Te la dejo de ejemplo, no es igual al tuyo pero puedes hacerlo de esta forma

```
public class JasperUtil {

private static final String PREFIX = "/resources/reports/";
private static final String SUFFIX = ".jasper";

public JasperUtil() {
}

public static ReporteJasper jasperReportPDF(String reportName, String nombreArchivo, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Map params, DataSource ds) throws SQLException {

    ReporteJasper reporte = null;
    String fileName;
    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
    ExternalContext eContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

    try {

        InputStream stream = eContext.getResourceAsStream(PREFIX + reportName + SUFFIX);

        if (stream != null) {

            ServletContext sContext = (ServletContext) eContext.getContext();
            String realPath = sContext.getRealPath("/resources/reports/");
            String fileSeparator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
            realPath += fileSeparator;
            params.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, new Locale("es", "GT"));

            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(stream, params, conn);

            fileName = nombreArchivo;

            JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, realPath + fileName);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING, "UTF-8");

            exporter.exportReport();

            reporte = new ReporteJasper();
            reporte.setFileName(fileName);
            reporte.setPages(jasperPrint.getPages().size());
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        conn.close();
    }
    return reporte;
}

public static ReporteJasper jasperReportXLS(String reportName, String nombreArchivo, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Map params, DataSource ds) throws SQLException {

    ReporteJasper reporte = null;

    String fileName;
    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

    ExternalContext eContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

    try {
        InputStream stream = eContext.getResourceAsStream(PREFIX + reportName + SUFFIX);

        if (stream != null) {

            ServletContext sContext = (ServletContext) eContext.getContext();
            String realPath = sContext.getRealPath("/resources/reports/");
            String fileSeparator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
            realPath += fileSeparator;
            params.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, new Locale("es", "GT"));
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(stream, params, conn);

            fileName = nombreArchivo;

            JRXlsExporter exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
            exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, realPath + fileName);
            exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.FALSE);
            exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
            exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
            exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);

            exporter.exportReport();

            reporte = new ReporteJasper();
            reporte.setFileName(fileName);
            reporte.setPages(jasperPrint.getPages().size());

        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        conn.close();
    }

    return reporte;
}

public static ReporteJasper jasperReportTxt(String reportName, String nombreArchivo, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Map params, DataSource ds) throws SQLException {

    ReporteJasper reporte = null;

    String fileName;
    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

    ExternalContext eContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    try {
        InputStream stream = eContext.getResourceAsStream(PREFIX + reportName + SUFFIX);

        if (stream != null) {

            ServletContext sContext = (ServletContext) eContext.getContext();
            String realPath = sContext.getRealPath("/resources/reports/");
            String fileSeparator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
            realPath += fileSeparator;

            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(stream, params, conn);

            fileName = nombreArchivo;

            JRExporter exporter = new JRTextExporter();
            exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
            //exporter.setParameter(JRTextExporterParameter.LINE_SEPARATOR, "\r\n");
            exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleWriterExporterOutput(realPath + fileName));
            exporter.exportReport();

            reporte = new ReporteJasper();
            reporte.setFileName(fileName);
            reporte.setPages(jasperPrint.getPages().size());

        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        conn.close();
    }
    return reporte;
}

public static ReporteJasper jasperReportCsv(String reportName, String nombreArchivo, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Map params, DataSource ds) throws SQLException {

    ReporteJasper reporte = null;

    String fileName;
    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

    ExternalContext eContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    try {
        InputStream stream = eContext.getResourceAsStream(PREFIX + reportName + SUFFIX);

        if (stream != null) {

            ServletContext sContext = (ServletContext) eContext.getContext();
            String realPath = sContext.getRealPath("/resources/reports/");
            String fileSeparator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
            realPath += fileSeparator;

            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(stream, params, conn);

            fileName = nombreArchivo;

            JRExporter exporter = new JRCsvExporter();
            exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
            //exporter.setParameter(JRTextExporterParameter.LINE_SEPARATOR, "\r\n");
            exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleWriterExporterOutput(realPath + fileName));
            exporter.exportReport();

            reporte = new ReporteJasper();
            reporte.setFileName(fileName);
            reporte.setPages(jasperPrint.getPages().size());

        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        conn.close();
    }
    return reporte;
}

public static ReporteJasper jasperReportNewTxt(String reportName, String nombreArchivo, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Map params, DataSource ds) throws SQLException {

    ReporteJasper reporte = null;

    String fileName;
    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

    ExternalContext eContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    try {
        InputStream stream = eContext.getResourceAsStream(PREFIX + reportName + SUFFIX);

        if (stream != null) {

            ServletContext sContext = (ServletContext) eContext.getContext();
            String realPath = sContext.getRealPath("/resources/reports/");
            String fileSeparator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
            realPath += fileSeparator;

            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(stream, params, conn);

            fileName = nombreArchivo;

            JRExporter exporter = new JRTextExporter();
            exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
            //exporter.setParameter(JRTextExporterParameter.LINE_SEPARATOR, "\r\n");
            exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleWriterExporterOutput(realPath + fileName));
            exporter.exportReport();

            reporte = new ReporteJasper();
            reporte.setFileName(fileName);

            if (jasperPrint.getPages() != null) {
                reporte.setPages(jasperPrint.getPages().size());
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        conn.close();
    }
    return reporte;
}
 }
```